# Run CircleCI job if any job in the workflow fails

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

In CircleCI, I know it's possible to run a step only if the job that contains it has failed, but can the same thing be done with jobs (without adding an extra failure handling step to every job)?

Specifically, I'm trying to send a slack notification if any job (e.g. checkout) in a workflow fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a simple way to do that; at the job level there's no equivalent to the step-level `when: on_fail` attribute.

All I can suggest is to use [Dynamic Config](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config/). Your "Setup Workflow" would include the main jobs you want to check the outcome of, plus a "waiter" job that:

1. Monitors the status of the main jobs, and once they have all completed it checks if any of them has a `Failed` status.
2. If there's at least one `Failed`, the "waiter" job sets a parameter to `true` (for example, `{ "extra-job": true }` that you pass to the [`continue` command of the `circleci/continuation` orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/continuation#commands-continue) (via the command's `parameters` parameter), along with the "continuation" `config.yml` (which will only include the job that sends a slack notification).

You can find an example of a "waiter" job in [this CircleCI Discuss post](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/workaround-run-jobs-sequentially-regardless-of-the-outcome-of-the-required-jobs/40807). It doesn't include the part where you check for `Failed` statuses and sets the JSON object that'll be later used as a parameter; you'll need to add that.

In the "continuation" config:

1. You'll need to declare a boolean pipeline parameter `extra-job` with a default value of `false`
2. The execution of the one workflow that has the "Slack job" [will be conditioned](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#logic-statement-examples) on the `extra-job` pipeline parameter being `true`:

   ```
   when: << pipeline.parameters.extra-job >>
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Geez, if that's really the only other way to do this, I think I'd rather just add an extra failure handling step to all my jobs. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Now maybe there's a simpler way that I'm missing, so take my suggestion with a pinch of salt :D

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same situation - running a job/step if the previous one failed.

After some digging I found it, a `when: on_fail` condition on the `step` level

reference
[CircleCI Docs](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043188514-How-to-Retry-a-Failed-Step-with-when-Attribute-)